# Error WindowLeaked al mostrar un Dialog

Tags: java, android

Realizando algunas pruebas para mostrar un cuadro de dialogo personalizado de la clase `Dialog`, me está lanzando un error del tipo "`android.view.WindowLeaked`" al girar la pantalla cuando se está mostrando. Por lo que he leído en Internet es un error debido a que muestro el cuadro de dialogo cuando la actividad ya no existe, pero no se como solucionarlo.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Dialog oDialog = new Dialog(this);
        oDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_error);
        oDialog.setCancelable(false);
        oDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        oDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Añado traza del error:

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9af0c50
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity app.test.myapplication.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ca325cd V.E...... R....... 0,0-180,356} that was originally added here
                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:375)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
                 at app.test.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)`
```

Comment: Quizás esto te ayude...http://code.hootsuite.com/orientation-changes-on-android/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error:

> MainActivity has leaked window ... that was originally added here

Indica que al rotar la `activity` que genero el Diálogo, esta se destruye y el Diálogo no encuentra la `Activity` sobre la cual el diálogo se creo originalmente.

Puedes definir en tu `Activity` dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` que no destruya la `Activity` al rotar:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    .../>
        ...
</activity>
```

Otra opción es determinar cuando la Activity va a ser destruida y evitar la creación del Dialogo:

```
 static boolean isAvailable = false;

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();

     isAvailable = true;

  } 

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();

     isAvailable = false;

  }
```

Para que en los puntos donde deseas crear el Dialogo no se muestre si la Actividad esta a punto de ser destruida:

```
 if(isAvailable){ //Actividad Activa
    Dialog oDialog = new Dialog(this);
    oDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_error);
    oDialog.setCancelable(false);
    oDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    oDialog.show();
  }
```

Comment: Me funcionó. Opté por la segunda opción para controlar cuando puede ser mostrado el dialogo o no. Gracias.

Comment: Excelente,  en ocasiones se requiere que la Activity se vuelva a crear por lo tanto la primer opción no aplica, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba primero inflando la vista del dialog antes de pasarselo

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_error, null)
Dialog oDialog = new Dialog(this);
oDialog.setContentView(view);
oDialog.setCancelable(false);
oDialog.show();
```